# What is the difference between "mincing" and "grinding"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What, if any, are essential differences between ***mincing*** and ***grinding***?

I tend to associate *mincing* with soft foods (other materials?) such as meat. In particular, [Merriam
Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mince) has the following (for the transitive verb):

> 1. a : to cut or chop into very small pieces
>      b :  to subdivide minutely; especially : to damage by cutting up
> 2. :  to utter or pronounce with affectation
> 3. a: *archaic* :  minimize
>      b :  to restrain (words) within the bounds of decorum

Here 3.a points out the etymology and maybe the technique of mincing, while 3.b suggest metaphorical usage (*mince one's words*).

*Grinding* might connote harder materials, such as pepper or nuts. Again from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/grind) (transitive verb):

> 1. to reduce to powder or small fragments by friction (as with the teeth)
> 2. to press together and move with a rotating or back-and-forth motion—see bruxism

Etymonline gives OE *grindan* "to rub together, grate, scrape" and earlier roots with the same meaning.

Apparently, one can also *grind beef*, for example.

Is there any difference in the technique of *mincing* and *grinding* different materials? Or in the intensity of crushing? In the accompanying sounds? (Hopefully *grinding one's teeth* is mainly about the sound, not producing anything.)

Or is it just a matter of collocation — *mince* is customary with some materials, *grind* with other materials?

Comment: British *mince* their beef and sell it as *minced beef*. Americans *grind* theirs and sell it as *ground beef*. But the machines they use and the nature of the end product are to all intents identical.

Comment: @WS2 So you propose the difference is regional (BrE vs AmE) as regards meat. No difference otherwise?

Comment: I've always perceived *mincing* to be *chopping up finely*, i.e. using a sharp edge, and grinding to be *rub against a hard, flat surface*. The results may or may not be similar, but the processes are different (AmE speaker).

Comment: Well, if you're talking about the way someone walks there's a huge difference.

Comment: You might find [this sample ontology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf) of some use. It's a handout from my [lexical semantics class](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/420syllabus04.pdf).

Comment: ("Grinding" beef and grinding, say, garlic are two entirely different processes.  A "meat grinder" is really a sort of chopper, and truth be told, the result is similar to mincing.)

Comment: @JohnLawler I grew up in the butchery trade and did most of those things at some time in my youth. The only one I note that is missing is *boning out*, which involves getting the last strands of meat off the bones to go into the mincer for sausages. Before Christmas we would work long hours *boning out* for making sausage meat, with which people stuffed their turkeys.

Comment: In principle, _mincing_ is slicing/chopping smallish longitudinal segments (say max 1cm long, and 1-2mm thick. This makes onions, for instance, basically dissolve when cooked; meat chopped this way is called _minced meat_ or _mincemeat_ and a medieval sweet/savory pie is named after it. _Grind,_ on the other hand, is something you don't do with a knife -- it means repeatedly scraping and scratching some surface with a tool, which is often round so it can be powered. Thus _meat grinders_ are those big things with cranks that make meat for sausages and hamburgers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mincing has the connotation of being cut with an instrument with a slicing edge, whereas grinding utilizes friction between two or more points. More about the physical action and tools involved rather than materials; although because of the difference in technique, they have varying effectivness with materials of varying consistency.

Both turns of phrase make sense describing said techniques metaphorically and physically, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Not quite pertinent to the original post, but -- what would be some good example of metaphorical grinding?

Comment: To grind down your opponent, to refer to the workday as the daily grind, and to have something grind your gears, I suppose. Those are the three I can think of. Besides mincing your words I'm not sure there are many other mincing metaphors. Maybe a mincing walk? Not sure if that is a metaphor or a proper physical descriptive rooted in the same archaic use of the 3b. definition.